# Trouble with upgrade to ubuntu xenial

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to get civi to run on Ubuntu xenial and drupal7. I installed the php5 repositories as per: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

I successfully upgraded my database to 4.7.7 but then I get stuck on a screen that shows the following:

localhost
Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error message
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: DB Error: no such field in civicrm_api3() (line 45 of /usr/share/drupal7/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).

Not sure if it has something to do with the access_compat errors I was getting while installing, things like this in my apache 2 error.log
[Tue May 17 14:22:54.236734 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 32145] [client 127.0.0.1:35040] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.63a720ea8e0f63f2f91fb59f72af16dc.log

Any leads appreciated!

Comment: I should add xenial uses mysql 5.7

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have gotten it. I upgraded to Ubuntu Xenial holding back with apt-mark all packages that matched drupal7, php, mysql and apache. Booted into my new system and all seems ok for now so I have my up to date desktop and a working civicrm setup. Thanks for listening.

Comment: good to hear you got things sorted. we were 'listening' ;-)